# Pass access token as URL query parameter?

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-graph-api

I am creating a bot, in which I have to send a HeroCard with an image obtained from Microsoft Graph. The problem is I can't send the access token to get the image this way.

I pass the image URL in the constructor for CardImage. There are no other constructors or functions to modify it, so I can't get the image with the token like I would normally and then send it to the CardImage.

Is there a way to pass the token as a url query string? I know this isn't recommended, so is there another way get this done? 
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe there is a way to do that, unless you somehow intercept the http request in the client and add the `Authorization: Bearer <token>` header.

However, there is a workaround that [MSGraph Sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/24.bot-authentication-msgraph) sort of uses.

1. [Prompt the user to log in](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/24.bot-authentication-msgraph/Dialogs/MainDialog.cs#L50)
2. [Get the photo, using the token](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/24.bot-authentication-msgraph/SimpleGraphClient.cs#L101) and [keep the base64 string of the photo](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/24.bot-authentication-msgraph/SimpleGraphClient.cs#L126).
3. Add the base64 string to the [`CardImage.Url`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.schema.cardimage.url?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable#Microsoft_Bot_Schema_CardImage_Url) property.

   - It accepts a base64 string so long as it's in the format: `"data:image/png;base64,<base64String>"`
   - [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49399182/10860086) may help you with this part

---

### For Posterity, the Relevant Code for Each Step

#### Step 1

In dialog constructor:

```cs
AddDialog(new OAuthPrompt(
    nameof(OAuthPrompt),
    new OAuthPromptSettings
    {
        ConnectionName = ConnectionName,
        Text = "Please login",
        Title = "Login",
        Timeout = 300000, // User has 5 minutes to login
    }));
```

First step:

```cs
private async Task<DialogTurnResult> PromptStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(OAuthPrompt), null, cancellationToken);
}
```

Next step:

```cs
private async Task<DialogTurnResult> LoginStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    // Get the token from the previous step. Note that we could also have gotten the
    // token directly from the prompt itself. There is an example of this in the next method.
    var tokenResponse = (TokenResponse)stepContext.Result;
    if (tokenResponse != null)
    {
        await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("You are now logged in."), cancellationToken);
        return await stepContext.PromptAsync(nameof(TextPrompt), new PromptOptions { Prompt = MessageFactory.Text("Would you like to do? (type 'me', 'send <EMAIL>' or 'recent')") }, cancellationToken);
    }

    await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("Login was not successful please try again."), cancellationToken);
    return await stepContext.EndDialogAsync();
}
```

Now we have the token.

#### Step 2

```cs
// Gets the user's photo
public async Task<PhotoResponse> GetPhotoAsync()
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + _token);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");

    using (var response = await client.GetAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo/$value"))
    {
        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            throw new HttpRequestException($"Graph returned an invalid success code: {response.StatusCode}");
        }

        var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
        var bytes = new byte[stream.Length];
        stream.Read(bytes, 0, (int)stream.Length);

        var photoResponse = new PhotoResponse
        {
            Bytes = bytes,
            ContentType = response.Content.Headers.ContentType?.ToString(),
        };

        if (photoResponse != null)
        {
            photoResponse.Base64String = $"data:{photoResponse.ContentType};base64," +
                                            Convert.ToBase64String(photoResponse.Bytes);
        }

        return photoResponse;
    }
}
```

#### Step 3

```cs
public static string ImageToBase64()
{
    var path = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~\imgs\testpic.PNG");
    Byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
    string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);

    return "data:image/png;base64," + base64String;
}

[...]

var imgUrl = ImageToBase64();
var cardImages = new List<CardImage>();
cardImages.Add(new CardImage(url: imgUrl));

var heroCard = new HeroCard
{
    Title = "BotFramework Hero Card",
    Subtitle = "Microsoft Bot Framework",
    Text = "Build and connect intelligent bots to interact with your users naturally wherever they are," +
            " from text/sms to Skype, Slack, Office 365 mail and other popular services.",
    Images = cardImages,
    Buttons = new List<CardAction> { new CardAction(ActionTypes.OpenUrl, "Get Started", value: "https://learn.microsoft.com/bot-framework") },
};

var attachment = heroCard.ToAttachment();
var message = MessageFactory.Attachment(attachment);
await context.PostAsync(message);
```